# SQL Server 2008 R2 Performance

Tags: sql-server, testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a table with 5 fields and containing 10millions record

I want to test that if my 20,000 Users simultaneously query on this table like.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field3 = 'test'
```

Then what will be the behaviour of my SQL Server 2008 R2

**So which tool or how can I test this scenario?**

Comment: Is this a realistic test? Will 20k users hit this at the same time? Do you have this query covered?

Comment: its client requirement so i have to proof that my application will work in this scenario thats it

Answer (score 0):

When we tested the system I work with we used HP LoadRunner. The place was in the HP test center in Böblingen. I had not the opportunity to go there my self but I heard that it was an impressive site with a **lot** of computers both to test against and to use as clients.

Answer (score 0):

Simultaneous is not a behavior that decoupled organic computing units engage in.   For user 1 you will go through the whole process for executing a query - for users 2-n you will be pulling from cache.

James Pulley

Moderator

-SQAForums WinRunner, LoadRunner

-YahooGroups LoadRunner, Advanced LoadRunner

-GoogleGroups lr-loadrunner

-LinkedIn LoadRunner (owner), LoadRunnerByTheHour (owner)

Mercury Alum, 1996-2000

CTO, Newcoe Performance Engineering | LoadRunnerbyTheHour.com